# Como creo esta tabla pivote? +Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, base-de-datos

Mi duda viene por que estoy haciendo una tabla pivote entre la tabla usuarios y la tabla destinations_travel y claro, la sintaxis de crear las tablas pivote 
php artisan make:migration create_tabla1_tabla2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al ser una de las tablas con "_" laravel supongo que me lo hace mal, gracias de antemano

Comment: No se de que manera haz creado la tabla pero al final deberia de ir "_table", laravel omite en si el nombre de la migracion, lo que le interesa es lo de adentro, esto solo se usa para nosotros los programadores nos ayude a decir si es tabla, o añadiras algun campo, con "alter_" etc,

Comment: La convención esta bien ya que es en orden alfabético, y para crearla es solo hacer esto, php artisan make:migration create_destinations_travels_table

Comment: Cierto, al crear el pivote debo poner table detrás, muchísimas gracias compañero, pensé que la sintaxis servía para algo más, como persona con más reputación en el foro me recomiendas dejar la pregunta o la elimino?

Comment: Puedes dejarla, solo autrespondete y marca como respuesta, aunque no lo creas puede que exista gente que tiene la misma duda o problema y encontrara esta pregunta y bueno de algo servira, recuerda que ninguna pregunta es tonta, tonto el que no pregunta (aunque preguntas cuanto es 2+2 xd)

Answer (score 2):

Como ha respondido el compañero @Dohko19 el error estaba que a la hora de crear me faltaba añadir el _table al final del comando:

```
php artisan make:migration create_destinations_travels_table
```